# Running script existing in another folder

Tags: bash, sh

I have two scripts in undermentioned folders:

- /folder_aaa/bbb/ddd/1.sh
- /folder_aaa/ccc/eee/2.sh

I would like to run 2.sh script from 1.sh script.
How should I write a path to 2.sh script ?

1.sh:

```
DIR=/../../ccc/eee/
SCRIPT_NAME="2.sh"

${DIR}/${SCRIPT_NAME}
```

Is above code (especially dir referention) ok ?

Comment: you can call file name directly like : ../../ccc/eee/2.sh . or ./folder_aaa/ccc/eee/2.sh or via bash command like : bash ../../ccc/eee/2.sh

Comment: you should _not_ end a path with a `/` unless you plan on referencing a file within that directory: __OK:__ `thing=/usr/bin/echo`, __NOT OK:__ `thing=/usr/bin/`, __OK:__ `thing=/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use `../../<DIRS>` because `..` will change depending on where *you* are, that is what `$PWD` is; rather than where the script using `..` *is*.

#### Using `realpath` and `dirname`

```bash
startdir="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
script="2.sh"
"$startdir"/../../"$script"
```

#### Using the absolute path

If you don't have access to `realpath` and `dirname` or don't want to use them: if you know that the location of `2.sh` and `1.sh` will *never* change, then you should fine using an absolute path to `2.sh`

```bash
"$HOME"/code/scripts/2.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths should not begin with `/` (they can, but since `/` is its own parent, any number of leading `/..` are redundant). Your `DIR` is equivalent to `/ccc/eee`. So you would want

```
DIR=../../ccc/eee
SCRIPT_NAME="2.sh"
${DIR}/${SCRIPT_NAME}
```

*However*, this assumes that the location of `1.sh` will never change relative to `2.sh`. You might just use the absolute path of `2.sh` instead:

```
DIR=/folder_aaa/ccc/eee
```

That, of course, assumes that the absolute path of `2.sh` won't change. Which one you use is a matter of preference and how the locations of `1.sh` and `2.sh` relate to each other.